# Regular expressions in stored procedures

Tags: regex, stored-procedures

Can a regular expression be used inside a stored procedure? If it can, how? Can you give some examples of how to do it?

Comment: Which DBMS is this pertaining to?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Generally, yes.

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/obe10gdb/develop/regexp/regexp.htm

MS SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Some more:

PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

DB2: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html

Informix: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/db_regexp.html

SQL Anywhere: http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2009/06/using-regular-expressions-with-sql-anywhere/

Comment: More options for MS SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120358/sql-server-2005-how-can-i-do-a-reg-exp-in-in-t-sql/4120499#4120499