# SQL Server 2005 - How can I do a Reg Exp in T-SQL

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005

Is there any way I can perform a Regular Expression search using T-SQL in SQL Server 2005 without having to load a .Net Assembly?

Answer (score 1):

It [seems](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql) that you can do it with VBScript, but it's not very pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way I know is by using a CLR udf as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: Also linked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650018/regular-expressions-in-stored-procedures

Answer (score 1):

Dan Farino seems to have written an [SP for SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xp_pcre.aspx) exactly for the purpose of using regex without having to install a .NET framework for CLR. Looks promising.

Comment: It's not a Perl-based library, it just uses a syntax that's compatible with Perl.